# PySpark Column Values Lagging and Labelling

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input spark dataframe is;

```
Client  Date        Due_Day
A      2017-01-01   Null
A      2017-02-01   Null
A      2017-03-01   Null
A      2017-04-01   Null
A      2017-05-01   Null
A      2017-06-01   35
A      2017-07-01   Null
A      2017-08-01   Null
A      2017-09-01   Null
A      2017-10-01   Null
A      2017-11-01   Null
A      2017-12-01   Null
B      2017-01-01   Null
B      2017-02-01   Null
B      2017-03-01   Null
B      2017-04-01   Null
B      2017-05-01   Null
B      2017-06-01   Null
B      2017-07-01   Null
B      2017-08-01   Null
B      2017-09-01   Null
B      2017-10-01   78
B      2017-11-01   Null
B      2017-12-01   Null
```

My desired spark dataframe is;

```
Client  Date    Due_Day  Date_lag   Result
A   2017-01-01  Null     -115       Current
A   2017-02-01  Null     -85        Current
A   2017-03-01  Null     -55        Current
A   2017-04-01  Null     -25        Current
A   2017-05-01  Null      5         1-30 day
A   2017-06-01  35                  31-60 day
A   2017-07-01  Null                Paid
A   2017-08-01  Null                OK
A   2017-09-01  Null                OK
A   2017-10-01  Null                OK
A   2017-11-01  Null                OK
A   2017-12-01  Null                OK
B   2017-01-01  Null     -192       Current
B   2017-02-01  Null     -162       Current
B   2017-03-01  Null     -132       Current
B   2017-04-01  Null     -102       Current
B   2017-05-01  Null     -72        Current
B   2017-06-01  Null     -42        Current
B   2017-07-01  Null     -12        Current
B   2017-08-01  Null      18        1-30 days
B   2017-09-01  Null      48        31-60 days
B   2017-10-01  78        78        61-90 days
B   2017-11-01  Null                Paid
B   2017-12-01  Null                OK
```

I want to get the Result column according to Due_day and Client Column.
In the months before Due_Day, 30 days should be subtracted.
The month after Due_Day should be paid and the following months should be Ok.

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: can there be more than one non-NULL Due_Day for the same Client?

Comment: No, just one for the same client.

Comment: Any idea about pyspark code? Really helpful for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use Window aggregate function to find *effective_due_day*(which has the **non-NULL** Due_Day) and its corresponding *due_date*(`Date`) and *due_month* `ceil(effective_due_day/30)` for each row of the same Client, calculate the *month_diff* between `Date` and `due_date`, and then do some math to retrieve the desired columns: (assume all `Date`s are on the first day of the month):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('Client')

df1 = df.select(
    "*",
    F.expr("max(IF(Due_Day is not NULL, Date, NULL))").over(w1).alias('due_date'),
    F.max('Due_Day').over(w1).alias('effective_due_day')
)

df_new = df1.withColumn('due_month', F.ceil(F.col('effective_due_day')/30)) \
    .withColumn('month_diff', F.months_between("due_date","Date").cast('int')) \
    .withColumn("Date_lag", F.expr("IF(month_diff>0, int(effective_due_day-30*month_diff), null)")) \
    .withColumn("Result", F.expr("""
      CASE
        WHEN month_diff = -1 THEN 'Paid'
        WHEN month_diff < 0 THEN 'OK'
        WHEN due_month > month_diff THEN concat(1+(due_month-month_diff-1)*30, '-', (due_month-month_diff)*30, ' days' )
        ELSE 'Current'
      END
    """))
```

**Result:**

```
df_new.show(30)
+------+----------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|Client|      Date|Due_Day|  due_date|effective_due_day|due_month|month_diff|Date_lag|    Result|
+------+----------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
|     B|2017-01-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         9|    -192|   Current|
|     B|2017-02-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         8|    -162|   Current|
|     B|2017-03-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         7|    -132|   Current|
|     B|2017-04-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         6|    -102|   Current|
|     B|2017-05-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         5|     -72|   Current|
|     B|2017-06-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         4|     -42|   Current|
|     B|2017-07-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         3|     -12|   Current|
|     B|2017-08-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         2|      18| 1-30 days|
|     B|2017-09-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         1|      48|31-60 days|
|     B|2017-10-01|     78|2017-10-01|               78|        3|         0|    null|61-90 days|
|     B|2017-11-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|        -1|    null|      Paid|
|     B|2017-12-01|   null|2017-10-01|               78|        3|        -2|    null|        OK|
|     A|2017-01-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         5|    -115|   Current|
|     A|2017-02-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         4|     -85|   Current|
|     A|2017-03-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         3|     -55|   Current|
|     A|2017-04-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         2|     -25|   Current|
|     A|2017-05-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         1|       5| 1-30 days|
|     A|2017-06-01|     35|2017-06-01|               35|        2|         0|    null|31-60 days|
|     A|2017-07-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -1|    null|      Paid|
|     A|2017-08-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -2|    null|        OK|
|     A|2017-09-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -3|    null|        OK|
|     A|2017-10-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -4|    null|        OK|
|     A|2017-11-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -5|    null|        OK|
|     A|2017-12-01|   null|2017-06-01|               35|        2|        -6|    null|        OK|
+------+----------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
```

**Note:** if you want to show `Date_lag` on the due_date, adjust `IF(diff>0,..)` to `IF(diff>=0,..)`